# split and separate result set values from database and set into text fields

Tags: java

```
while (rs.next()) {

    rs.getString(13);

    txt_particular2.setText("");
    txt_particular2.setEditable(false);

    txt_particular3.setText("");
    txt_particular3.setEditable(false);

    txt_particular4.setText("");
    txt_particular4.setEditable(false);
}
```

How do I split values in "rs.getString(13)"  and set into text fields separately?

Comment: How the value of `rs.getString(13);` looks like and where it should be splitted?

Comment: "rs.getString(13)" has values like Metal,Almunium,CrushSand and i want to set these value separately in different text fields.

Comment: And you want to spilt it at blank?

Comment: I want to break these values and set separately with different text fields. Like Metal in "txt_particular1.setText(rs.getString)" ,  Aluminium  in "txt_particular2.setText(rs.getString)" and CrushSand in Metal in "txt_particular3.setText(rs.getString)"

Answer (score 0):

Split the result of `rs.getString(13)` using:

```
String[] splitted =  rs.getString(13).split(",");
```

and than you can call

```
txt_particular2.setText(splitted[0]);
txt_particular3.setText(splitted[1]);
txt_particular4.setText(splitted[2]);
```

Of curse you have to check if the string is not null, if the length of the Array is as expected and so on.

Comment: its saying Array Out of bond exception -1

Comment: @CannonSuyash in which line?

Comment: try {
    String s = (String) master.getSelectedItem();
    con = Connect.ConnectDB();

    PreparedStatement st = con
      .prepareStatement("select pericular from challan_new where  date >= '" + d + "' and   date <= '"+ d1 + "'");

    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();

     
    String[] arr = null;
    while (rs.next()) {
        String em = rs.getString(1);
        arr = em.split("\n");
        for (int i =0; i < arr.length; i++){
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
          txt_particular1.setText(Arrays.toString(arr[0]));
        }
    }
    
   }

Comment: Why `Arrays.toString(arr[0]))`?

Comment: Where yoo get These exception? Array Out of bond exception -1